# Pythonic way to walk a self-referential dictionary

Tags: dictionary, python-3.x, python

I have a dictionary where entry values can reference another entry by key eventually ending with no entry for the current value or when "-" is encountered.  The goal of this data structure is to find the parent for each entry and also transform "-" into None.  For instance take:

```py
d = {'1': '-', '0': '6', '3': '1', '2': '3', '4': '5', '6': '9'}
```

- '1' is a root that maps to '-' so it should result in *None*.
- '0' has a parent of '6', which has a parent of '9' so it should result in '9'.
- '3' has a parent of '1', which maps to '-' so it should result in *None*.
- '2' has a parent of '3',which has a parent of '1' which maps to '-' so it should result in *None*.
- '4' should remain with parent of '5'
- '6' should remain with parent of '9'

My verbose solution is as follows:

```py
d = {'1': '-', '0': '6', '3': '1', '2': '3', '4': '5', '6': '9'}
print(d)
for dis, rep in d.items():
    if rep == "-":
        d[dis] = None
        continue

    while rep in d:
        rep = d[rep]
        if rep == "-":
            d[dis] = None
            break
    else:
        d[dis] = rep
print(d)
```

The output is:

```py
{'1': '-', '0': '6', '3': '1', '2': '3', '4': '5', '6': '9'}
{'1': None, '0': '9', '3': None, '2': None, '4': '5', '6': '9'}
```

The result is correct.  The "1" element has no parent and the "2"/"3" element point back to "1".  They should also have no parent.

Is there a terser pythonic way to accomplish this using Python 3+?

Comment: can you clarify what you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: as @ch3ka said. Your input/output doesn't match the text either. To get your given output from your given input, you would just do `{k: None for k in d}` but I doubt that is what you want.

Comment: I have updated the original question with more detail and corrected the code.

Comment: So is that output what you want? You don't want `{'1': None, '3': 1, '2': 1}`?

Comment: I've updated the explanation of the results.  I want to flatten every entry so that I no longer have to traverse up the dictionary.

Comment: Is `{'1': None, '3': None, '2': None}` the correct output? Can you show an example where not all the values end up being `None`?

Comment: If you always follow the links until you reach `-` (which you replace with `None`), then you will always have values of `None`, right?  Is there a counter example?

Comment: Updated the example to hopefully explain all possible results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To "walk" the dictionary, just do the lookups in a loop until there are no more:

```
>>> def walk(d, val):
        while val in d:
            val = d[val]
        return None if val == '-' else val

>>> d = {'1': '-', '0': '6', '3': '1', '2': '3', '4': '5', '6': '9'}
>>> print {k: walk(d, k) for k in d}
{'1': None, '0': '9', '3': None, '2': None, '4': '5', '6': '9'}
```

Comment: I like this dictionary comprehension approach.  For each key in the dictionary return a new dictionary entry with that key plus the walked value.  Am I reading that correctly?

Comment: Doesn't this mean you will walk over lots of subbranches multiple times?

Comment: I would think that is true, because a new dictionary is being built.  Each walk's key / value result will not affect a successive one.

Comment: I don't think you care about rewalking common subbranches.  The walk loop is very cheap.

Comment: I like the dictionary comprehension approach.  The use of dictionary comprehension and terseness convinces me it is pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function like this

```
def recursive_get(d, k):
    v = d[k]
    if v == '-':
        v = d[k] = None
    elif v in d:
        v = d[k] = recursive_get(d, v)
    return v
```

When you use `recursive_get` to access a key it will modify the values as it traverses.
This means you don't waste time packing up branches that are never needed

```
>>> d = {'1': '-', '3': '1', '2': '3'}
>>> recursive_get(d, '3')
>>> d
{'1': None, '3': None, '2': '3'}         # didn't need to visit '2'

>>> d = {'1': '-', '3': '1', '2': '3'}
>>> recursive_get(d, '2')
>>> d
{'1': None, '3': None, '2': None}
```

If you wish to just force `d` into it's final state, simply loop through all the keys

```
for k in d:
    recursive_get(d, k)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'waste time packing up branches that are never needed'?

Comment: @tonysbd, in you updated example, try doing `recursive_get(d, 0)`, you see you get the return value of `'9'` and `d` has been modified just on the branch involving '0','6' and '9', ie `d = {'1': '-', '0': '9', '3': '1', '2': '3', '4': '5', '6': '9'}`.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, but I'm looking to solve all branches for the dictionary.

Comment: @tonysbd, see the last two lines of my answer to solve all the branches

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to post some profiling statistics on the three approaches so far:

```py
Running original procedural solution.
5 function calls in 0.221 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.221    0.221 <string>:1(<module>)
    1    0.221    0.221    0.221    0.221 test.py:12(verbose)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.221    0.221 {built-in method exec}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'items' of 'dict' objects}

885213
Running recursive solution.
     994022 function calls in 1.252 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.000    0.000    1.252    1.252 <string>:1(<module>)
994018    0.632    0.000    0.632    0.000 test.py:27(recursive)
    1    0.620    0.620    1.252    1.252 test.py:35(do_recursive)
    1    0.000    0.000    1.252    1.252 {built-in method exec}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}

885213
Running dict comprehension solution.
     994023 function calls in 1.665 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.059    0.059    1.665    1.665 <string>:1(<module>)
994018    0.683    0.000    0.683    0.000 test.py:40(walk)
    1    0.000    0.000    1.606    1.606 test.py:45(dict_comprehension)
    1    0.923    0.923    1.606    1.606 test.py:46(<dictcomp>)
    1    0.000    0.000    1.665    1.665 {built-in method exec}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}

885213
```

Below is the code to run the three approaches:

```py
import cProfile
import csv
import gzip

def gzip_to_text(gzip_file, encoding="ascii"):
    with gzip.open(gzip_file) as gzf:
        for line in gzf:
            yield str(line, encoding)

def verbose(d):
    for dis, rep in d.items():
        if rep == "-":
            d[dis] = None
            continue

        while rep in d:
            rep = d[rep]
            if rep == "-":
                d[dis] = None
                break
        else:
            d[dis] = rep
    return d

def recursive(d, k):
    v = d[k]
    if v == '-':
        v = d[k] = None
    elif v in d:
        v = d[k] = recursive(d, v)
    return v

def do_recursive(d):
    for k in d:
        recursive(d, k)
    return d

def walk(d, val):
    while val in d:
        val = d[val]
    return None if val == '-' else val

def dict_comprehension(d):
    return {k : walk(d, k) for k in d}

# public dataset pulled from url: ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/gene/DATA/gene_history.gz
csvr = csv.reader(gzip_to_text("gene_history.gz"), delimiter="\t", quotechar="\"")
d = {rec[2].strip() : rec[1].strip() for rec in csvr if csvr.line_num > 1}
print("Running original procedural solution.")
cProfile.run('d = verbose(d)')
c = 0
for k, v in d.items():
    c += (1 if v is None else 0)
print(c)
print("Running recursive solution.")
cProfile.run('d = do_recursive(d)')
c = 0
for k, v in d.items():
    c += (1 if v is None else 0)
print(c)
print("Running dict comprehension solution.")
cProfile.run('d = dict_comprehension(d)')
c = 0
for k, v in d.items():
    c += (1 if v is None else 0)
print(c)
```